# Why does client hijacking only works while the browser is online?

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, oauth, websecurity, client-side-attacks

I was reading the [OAuth 2.0 for Browser-Based Apps](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps) draft, and went into the mailing list discussions. [In the emails](https://mailarchive.ietf.org/arch/browse/oauth/?q=draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps&qdr=y) there's this bit of text:

> Stating that using stolen tokens is the same as sending requests through a
> compromised client in the user’s browser (client hijacking) is
> categorically false. Here are two concrete differences:
>
> Stolen refresh tokens give an attacker long-term access in the name of
> the user. Client hijacking only works as long as the user’s browser is
> online and the client is effectively running. Stolen access tokens
> give an attacker unfettered access to any resource server that accepts
> it. Client hijacking forces the attacker to play by the rules of the
> client. For example, an attacker can abuse a stolen token with fake
> origin headers to access a resource server that would accept the
> token, but has a CORS policy that rejects requests from the client’s
> origin

Why does client hijacking not work without an online browser with the client running? As far as I understand from client hijacking, it means an attacker is able to steal the session on the browser from a victim. Couldn't they use this session somewhere else to act maliciously?

Comment: The idea is that with client hijacking they can run code in the victims browsers, but they don't have direct access to the token. Perhaps the token is in a HttpOnly cookie.